# Trying to deploy from Springloops to Amazon EC2 Server

Tags: svn, ssh, amazon-ec2, sftp, springloops

I'm trying to set up an auto-deploy from my springloops SVN through SFTP, but apparently springloop's private/public key authentication doesn't work, so they advised me to use a standard password only authentication, only I can't figure out how to create an ssh account with just a standard username/password so that it can automatically deploy.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

springloops supports deployment using sftp and a key file for auth.

Answer (score 0):

Hey just wondering how you went with this?  I"ve just burned a few hours trying to get FTP working on my EC2 windows instance... then realised SFTP is the way forward (but dont have my key with me, doh!)

So Springloops SFTP doesn't work?  I was going to try this when i get home... i probably still will but if you have found a solution i'd love to hear it.

Comment: Yeah, you need to use SFTP.  In your ssh configuration file, you need to make sure that you allow password authentication.  Then once you fix that setting, you need to restart the ssh daemon (sudo /etc/init.d/sshd restart).  Then you need to add the user accounts (adduser command), and you then will be able to login.  Make sure you have file permissions set properly or your post-commit ftp sync hook will fail.